# Ionic: Why the detected device language is 'zz-ZZ'

Tags: ionic-framework, localization, pseudolocalization

In ionic `navigator.language` returns `en-US` on the browser and `zz-ZZ` on my Android device.

I've read that it is called [Pseudolocalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization).

Why does it happen? How can I get the real device language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject the `$locale` service and retrieve the device language using `$locale.id`

---